# Can someone explain how Java nested loops work with number patterns?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am having trouble understanding how nested loops and numbers patterns work. I have completed all of the patterns except 3. Can someone please help me with this code and explain how this works?

```
public class Patterns7{
    public Patterns7() {
    }

    public void displayPatternI(int lines) 
    {
        System.out.println("\n\tPattern I\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print (j + " " );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void displayPatternII (int lines) 
    {
        System.out.println("\n\tPattern II to be implemented\n");
        for (int i = 1;i <= lines; i++) 
        { 
            for(int j = i;j >= 1; j--) 
                System.out.print(j); 

            System.out.println(); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void displayPatternIII (int lines) 
    {
        System.out.println("\n\tPattern III  to be implemented\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
        {
            for (int space = 1; space <= lines-i; space++)
                System.out.print (" ");

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print (j + " ");

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Pattern III is supposed to look like this:

```
      6

     56

    456

   3456

  23456

 123456
```

But all I could get it to do was this:

```
      1

     1 2

    1 2 3

   1 2 3 4

  1 2 3 4 5

 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I am unsure of how to get the out put to start with 6 and decrease then increase.

Pattern V is supposed to look like this:

```
          1

        2 1 2

       3 2 1 2 3

      4 3 2 1 2 3 4

     5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5

    6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

But it comes out like this:

```
    1

     1 2 3

    1 2 3 4 5
```

Code:

```
public void displayPatternVI (int lines) 
{
    System.out.println("\n\tMy Own Pattern to be implemented\n");

    for (int i = 1; i <= lines/2; i++)
    {
        for (int space = 1; space <= (lines/2)-i; space++)
            System.out.print (" ");

        for (int j = 1; j <= (i*2)-1; j++)
            System.out.print (j + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= lines/2; i++)
    {
        for (int space = 1; space <= i-1; space++)
            System.out.print (" ");

        for (int j = 1; j <= lines-(i*2)+1; j++)
            System.out.print (j + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Pattern VI is supposed to look like this:

```
              1

            2 1 2

          3 2 1 2 3

        4 3 2 1 2 3 4

      5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5

    6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6

    6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6

      5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 

        4 3 2 1 2 3 4

          3 2 1 2 3

            2 1 2

              1
```

but it looks like this:

```
      1

     1 2 3

    1 2 3 4 5

    1 2 3 4 5

     1 2 3

      1
```

Can someone please help and explain to me how to this?

Comment: **Debugger:** "I can explain!!"

Comment: Very poorly asked question. Is this your homework?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun ok. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think I would re-ask this question, but narrow it down to one specific nested problem. Somebody will gladly explain to you the logic behind how to get started on it, and hopefully you'll be able to aplpy that to the other solutions.

Comment: @Kon is this the kind of site where everybody spends more time criticizing a question rather than answer it? If so, can you point me in the direction of a site that is more beginner friendly?

Comment: You can use (lines<maxLines). When you arrive to your maxNum set numAdd=-1& use number+=numAdd

Comment: You should at least make some effort to better "zoom in" on your problem, and isolate whats not working as you would expect. One of the qualities expected from a software developer is also being able to explain your problem well. Just posting tons of code and posting 'Solve this please!' is not the idea here. Are you really willing to  research and learn?

Comment: @KelliDavis you got two responses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really only supposed to ask one question at a time, but here's a solution to your first issue.  For `SIZE` equals 6:

> ```
>     6
>    56
>   456
>  3456
> 23456
> ```
>
> 123456

you would want something like:

```
String temp;

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    temp = "";

    for(int j = SIZE - i; j <= SIZE ; j++) 
    {
        temp += j;
    }

System.out.printf("%" + SIZE + "s\n", temp);
}
```

Try the second one on your own.

Comment: PS: Sometimes this site can be tough for newcomers.  Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  It may offer some helpful advice.

Comment: thank you for the help. I do not understand why you put String temp in there.

Comment: @KelliDavis - he's outputting each line as a string and not a number. first you construct each number as a string - 6, 56, 456 etc using the concatenation operator. the inner loop creates the number which is later used as output.

Comment: @divyanshm ok. so what exactly does i and j control? How do they work? is i the amount of rows and j the numbers? or vice versa?

Comment: @KelliDavis The best way to see this is to trace through the loop yourself.

Comment: `i` controls how many numbers we print, and `j` controls the actual numbers that get printed (calculated using `i`). When `i` is 0, we print 1 number, when it is 1, we print 2 numbers...`j` will be 6 when `i` is 0, it will go from 5 to 6 when `i` is 1, from 4 to 5 to 6 when  `i` is 2, etc...You're welcome, btw. Sorry, didn't mean to ignore your thank you.

Comment: @SteveP. thanks!! so when it says "lines - i" it means 6 - 1 then j++ is 5 to 6?

Comment: @KelliDavis For each iteration of the outer loop (from `i` = 0 to `i` = `SIZE`), the inner loop goes from `SIZE-i` to `SIZE`.  So, when `SIZE = 6` and `i` is 1 (second iteration of the outer loop), the inner loop goes from `j` = 5 to `j` = 6.  Then `i` becomes 2 and the inner loop goes from `j` = 4 to `j` = 6.

Comment: @KelliDavis  No problem. Not sure if there's any confusion about this part, but the correct formatting comes from the `printf` statement.  `printf("%6s," someString)` prints `someString` with at least 6 characters (meaning that spaces are inserted beforehand if `someString.length() < 6)`.  So, what I wrote inserts `SIZE` in as 6.  I did this because java doesn't provide `String` interpolation and hence you can't include an identifier inside the quotes (java would just print the identifier itself, ie it would print `SIZE` instead of 6).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void displayPatternIII (int lines) 
{
  System.out.println("\n\tPattern III  to be implemented\n");
    for (int i = lines; i >= 1; i--)
      {
        int space = 1;
        for (; space <= i-1; space++)
          System.out.print (" ");

        for (int j = space; j <= lines; j++)
          System.out.print (j);

        System.out.println();
      }
}
```

*Output:*

```
    Pattern III  to be implemented

     6
    56
   456
  3456
 23456
123456
```